# Using redshift with django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I want to connect to my redshift database from django. After changing settings.py I got following error :

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Column "django_migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial".
```

I googled it and got a bit smarter with this : 
[Using Django Multiple Databases with RedShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719478/using-django-multiple-databases-with-redshift)

If I'm right, it's not really possible to read/write data with django from/to redshift? If it is possible, what's the best way?

Thank you

ps: i can connect to my redshift db using psycopg2. But I want to do it with django so I don't need to rewrite all the code that is using the database in settings..