# django connectivity with redshift database

Tags: python, django

I am working on an django project. I am trying to connect django with a redshift database using postgresql_psycopg2 backend of django.

I am not able to migrate my database.

Can any one suggest relevant solutions? It will be very helpful.

Comment: What error are you getting? post that as well please

Comment: and how does your `DATABASES` settings look like?

Comment: database settings are :DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'test',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': '******',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '***************************.redshift.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': 8192,
    },
}

Comment: error : File "C:\Users\dhimam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 59, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (Column "django_migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial".

Comment: You can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719478/using-django-multiple-databases-with-redshift